# How to find the cross correlation between two time series over different periods?

Tags: r, time-series

I have two time series.
Each point in either time series is for a week. A week here is not exactly a calendar week, but the first week in a calendar year always starts from Jan 1, and the other weeks in the same year follow that, and the last week of the year may contain more than 7 days but no more than 13 days.

The first time series A is stored in a compressed (.gz) text file A.gz, which looks like (each week and the corresponding time series value are separated by a comma in a line):

```
week,value
20060101-20060107,0
20060108-20060114,5
...
20061217-20061223,0
20061224-20061230,0
20070101-20070107,0
20070108-20070114,4
...
20150903-20150909,0
20150910-20150916,1
```

The second time series B is similarly stored in a compressed (.gz) text file B.gz, but over a subset of period of A, which looks like:

```
week,value
20130122-20130128,509
20130129-20130204,204
...
20131217-20131223,150
20131224-20131231,148.0
20140101-20140107,365.0
20140108-20140114,45.0
...
20150305-20150311,0
20150312-20150318,364
```

I wonder how to calculate the cross correlation between the two time series A and B (up to a specified maximum lag), and plot A and B in a single plot, in R?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the `ccf` function that ships with R, I believe `plot` has a method for plotting the output of those things. Otherwise you can always add lines to a graph with `lines`. I would, however, consider using gglot2 for this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks. How shall I  associate the week timestamps with time series' points?

Comment: You might have to do some kind of conversion but I would start by letting R try to coerce the data into a time series object (which is a standard type) how to do that escapes me at the moment but probably something like: `myData <- as.timeSeries(myData)`